# Invalid identifier error in oracle although object present at schema level

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have object type present at schema level. I want to run a select query like:

```
SELECT to_cnf_pye_bse_obj(fap_inr_idr)
  FROM to_cnf_pye_rsp
 WHERE fap_inr_idr IN (
  SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(lc, 100000)*/ fap_inr_idr
    FROM TABLE (to_cnf_pye_bse_typ ) lc
);
```

It is giving me error:

> ORA-00904: "TO_CNF_PYE_BSE_TYP": invalid identifier

Is there some other way to execute the select statement?

Comment: What do you want to select from *type*? It is just a definition

Comment: SELECT to_cnf_pye_bse_obj(fap_inr_idr)
    FROM to_cnf_pye_rsp
     WHERE fap_inr_idr IN 
(SELECT /+ CARDINALITY(lc, 100000)/ fap_inr_idr FROM TABLE (to_cnf_pye_bse_typ )lc);

Comment: I see the code, but imagine yourself a DBMS and tell me, what the data do you expect to be in type *definition*? It is really unclear. The data should come from some producer (table, view, function, cursor etc), but not from definition.

Comment: Post your definition of *to_cnf_pye_bse_typ*. You can use the [TABLE function](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/using-the-table-operator-with-locally-defined-types-in-plsql-12cr1#associative-array-example) to select from but the object on the function must be a collection.